# Unable to infer schema when connecting to Redshift from Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have installed sparc to `/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/` and run python shell using

```
pyspark --jars spark-redshift_2.10-3.0.0-preview1.jar,RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.7.1003.jar,hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar,aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

from it's folder.

Then I am trying to read from there using following commands in shell:

```
JDBC='jdbc:redshift://blablabla.regionblabla.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/blabla?user=username&password=password'

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql_context.read \
    .option("url", JDBC) \
    .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
    .option("tempdir", "bucket") \
    .load()
```

And I get following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 165, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'
```

After some search I found some issues and answers that state that this could be because there are no data there. But requests show me that table is not empty. So, I guess I have some problems with connection. How to fix this? Maybe I have wrong versions of spark or that jars, or some jar missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to add AWS credentians using

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", KEYS[0])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", KEYS[1])
```

and add option to provide that same credentials to redshift:

```
.option('forward_spark_s3_credentials', 'true')
```